# Invalid hex values

Tags: python, hex

I'm using `hex(int('00000000', 2))` to convert a binary string into hex.

It works fine for all (output) values from `10` to `FF`, but its not padding `00` to `09` properly, and I'm seeing `0x0` to `0x9` instead of the `0x00` to `0x09` that I am expecting.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you going to use this to convert just one byte or an arbitrary number? As in, do you always expect two digits or any even number of digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hex()` will return the shortest string possible.

One alternative is to simply use:

```
"0x%02x" % int('00000000', 2)
```

Comment: Ahhh, OK. I foolishly thought that the base indicator of 2 would result in byte based hex, not a true arbitrary length hex value. Awesome, thank you. I understand what I was doing wrong! :)

Comment: Or, the slightly weirder (but just as valid) `"%#04x" % 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think that `hex(0)` should return `0x00`? `0x0` is semantically correct and is the shortest representation of the hexadecimal `0`. Consider this: when you write decimal zero, it is `0` not `00`. Or e.g. `0x9` == `00009` == `9`. And the latter is the natural non-redundant decimal representation of the number `9`.

Comment: Whilst `0x0` is semantically correct, and in that regard expected, my naive expectation is that it would return a valid byte value that can be functioned on - giving '0x0' as a 'binary' data element to a binary file writer is resulting in the string "0x0" being committed, not the byte `00`

Comment: I don't understand why you are using hex to write binary values to a file. Why not just use `struct` to convert integers into binary representation?

Answer (score 0):

`0x9` is a valid hexadecimal number equal to `0x09`. The `hex` method does not know how much padding to add)

You could use a regex to fix the padding and get "0x09" from "0x9"

```
number = re.sub('x(\d)$','x0\1',number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting to convert values to hex.

```
'0x{:02x}'.format(int('00000110', 2))
```